Did Phats & Small only earn 5000 GBP from the sales of their "Turn Around" track?
I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Phats_%26_Small&oldid=1231722309:

The song debuted at number three in the UK Singles Chart, before climbing to number two, with career sales of this hit amassing them £5,000 in total due to their recording contract.

5000 GBP sounds rather small given the song's popularity and no sources are given.
Did Phats & Small only earn 5000 GBP from the sales of their  "Turn Around" track?

Looks like the addition of that line was made by an unregistered user without edit summary.
